# Algorithm used by Counter in python collections package?

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to check if a set of words is present in another set of words, for example

```
list1=['Hello','World']
list2=['Hello','World','Good','Bye']
```

I wrote the following code to check if the words present in list1 are also present in list2

```
def check(list1,list2):
 for l in list1:
  if l not in list2:
   return False
 return True
```

But this code fails for large input.Then i found following code in net which works for all the input

```
from collections import Counter
def check(list1,list2):
 return not (Counter(list1) - Counter(list2))
```

Can anyone tell me what algorithm does Counter use or provide any other method using which same result can be achieved without using built in functions.

Comment: You can check out the [code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/collections/__init__.py) for `Counter`. Although no doubt some of the implementation is in C. It mentions `multiset` and gives some reference links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source code of [Counter](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l407) defines Counter as a bag or multiset.
The count process is in [update](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l528) method and it doesn't contain anything special - it just iterates over all elements and count their occurrence.

In your case [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) is enough:

```
def check(list1, list2):
    # all items from list1 in list2
    return set(list1) <= set(list2)
```

If you can't use `set` too I would suggest following:

1. sort both lists
2. iterate over different items of list1 (item1)
3. iterate over items of list2 until you rich item1 or the end of list2, which means items is not in list2, end list1 cycle.

I would take `2nlogn + 2n` time.

```
def check(list1, list2):
    j = 0
    prev = None
    for item1 in list1:
        if prev is not None and item1 == prev:
            continue

        while j < len(list2):
            if list2[j] == item1:
                break
            if list2[j] > item1:
                return False
            j += 1
        else:
            return False

        prev = item1
        j += 1

    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python 2.7.12**
Go over to your python installation and in Lib folder you will find a file called **collections.py**

Everything written between **line 555-563** is the algorithm used to populate a dictionary of words with their corresponding counts. Basically the output of Counter(list1) is a dictionary with words as keys and counts as values.

The thing that lets you subtract is present in the same file - **lines 652-669** (pasted below)

```
def __sub__(self, other):
        ''' Subtract count, but keep only results with positive counts.

        >>> Counter('abbbc') - Counter('bccd')
        Counter({'b': 2, 'a': 1})

        '''
        if not isinstance(other, Counter):
            return NotImplemented
        result = Counter()
        for elem, count in self.items():
            newcount = count - other[elem]
            if newcount > 0:
                result[elem] = newcount
        for elem, count in other.items():
            if elem not in self and count < 0:
                result[elem] = 0 - count
        return result
```